# Are there any API's I can integrate with to accept Cardano as a merchant?

Tags: api

I run a small tourism startup and I'm looking for an API I can integrate with to accept Cardano on our website. Does anything like this exist? Sadly, neither Coinbase Commerce nor Bitpay are currently supporting Cardano.

Answer (score 4):

To answer my own question, you can currently use https://nowpayments.io/,  https://adapay.finance/, or to roll your own solution https://blockfrost.io/.

There's also an ongoing petition to get Cardano added to BitPay.